# PHP: Save file to a specific directory

Tags: php, joomla

I have this diretorio.php file that grabs the user id in Joomla and creates a directory with that id (if it doesn't exist yet):

```
/* Get the current user id */
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$usr_id = $user->get('id');

/*Define the path to this user's directory */
$diretorio=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Apps/files/".$usr_id;

/*Create the user's directory if it doesn't exist */
if (!file_exists($diretorio) and !is_dir($diretorio)) {
    mkdir($diretorio, 0755);
};
```

Now, I want to save a file with data in an object, using an Ajax that triggers another PHP file to the same directory created above:

```
$myFile = $diretorio."/dados.json";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("não é possível abrir o ficheiro");
$stringData = $_POST['data'];
$stringData='{  "data":'.json_encode($stringData).'}';
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

However, the file isn't created. If I replace the first line to:

```
$myFile = "dados.json";
```

It will create the file in the same directory where this PHP script is stored.

Comment: I would recomment taking a look at the [Joomla File System Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_filesystem_package)

Comment: Have you configured PHP to display/log all kind of error messages? What does `fwrite()` return?

Comment: It doesn't return any error. Even when the reporting standard is set to maximum

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Joomla coding standards like so:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$usr_id = $user->get('id');

$diretorio = JPATH_SITE . "/Apps/files/" . $usr_id;

if (!JFolder::exists($diretorio)) {
    JFolder::create($diretorio, 0775);
}

$myFile = $diretorio."/dados.json";

$stringData = $_POST['data'];
$stringData = '{ "data":'.json_encode($stringData).'}';
JFile::write($myFile, $stringData);
```

`JPATH_SITE` is the root of your Joomla site

Comment: what I would recommend doing though is having your default file **dados.json** which is empty and moving it to the newly created folder before adding content to it and saving it

Comment: Thanks, I changed the coding standards, and it creates the directory but not the file dados.json in it. The file has to be in this specific directory since several users may be using it simultaneously.

Comment: Hmm that's odd. I have just tested the code on my site and it worked fine

Comment: If $myFile="dados.json" it creates the file in the same directory where the 2nd php script is located. If $myFile=$diretorio."/dados.json" then nothing happens.

Comment: ah the code is in 2 separate php files? Move it all into the same file and it will work

Comment: Yes, also tried that, like: $user = JFactory::getUser();
 $usr_id = $user->get('id');
 
 $myFile = JPATH_SITE."/Apps/files/".$usr_id."/dados.json"; But nothing happens

Comment: Ok well it can't be a Joomla libray importing issue as you said it's creating the folder. ok...copy and paste my code exactly how it is into one of your files, then copy and paste the following after the code: `var_dump($myFile);` and tell me what you get

Comment: erm ok. Do you think you will be able to upload the whole file to pastebin or somewhere else so I can test it?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I added more details in another question, please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254333/create-file-in-the-user-id-directory

Comment: Ah I believe it's due to your ajax request. If you execute the raw PHP, it will work ;)

Comment: I guess so, too. The problem is this is supposed to grab the data in an object and send it this directory/file in Json format. How do I manage to that without Ajax?

Comment: You could create a simple Joomla plugin. Check the Joomla docs on how to do this.