# Create file in the user id directory

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

What I'm trying to do is to create a file "dados.json" to a directory that matches the user_id in Joomla.

So, for example, user 15 will have a file ".../files/15/dados.json".

The contents of dados.json are the data contained in an object. I'm using Ajax to send the data to a PHP script escreve.php:

```
/*Get the user Id and create a directory with that id if it doesn't exist yet */
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $usr_id = $user->get('id'); 
    $diretorio = JPATH_SITE."/Apps/files/".$usr_id;
    if (!JFolder::exists($diretorio)) {
        JFolder::create($diretorio, 0775);
    };

    /*Get the data and save it to the user directory in file dados.json */
    $myFile = $diretorio."/dados.json";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("não é possível abrir o ficheiro");
    $stringData = $_POST['data'];
    $stringData='{  "data":'.json_encode($stringData).'}';
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
```

But this isn't working. The directory isn't created and neither is the file. I get no errors from PHP.

The ajax is the following:

```
$parent.find('button[name=save]').click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "../Apps/php/escreve.php",
    data:{'data': handsontable.getData()}, //returns all cells' data
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (res) {
      if (res.result === 'ok') {
        $console.text('Data saved!');
      }
      else {
        $console.text('Save error1');
      }
    },
    error: function () {
      $console.text('Save error2');
    }
  });
});
```

This is logging Save error2 to the console.

Any help please!?

Comment: I thought you said in your previous question that the folder was being created, but the file wasnt

Comment: Yes, previously, the folder was being created by a raw php script while the file was responding to an ajax request.

Comment: Fire up Chrome and check what the 'Network tab' in the development tools says when ajax sends the data! Probably the php file is not been accessed at all.

Comment: I get status 200 for escreve.php

Comment: You can check the JSFiddle where in the Css separator I'm posting the escreve.php file contents here: http://jsfiddle.net/muDbT/

Comment: you're still using raw PHP for the creation of the file. I wrote some code for you in your previous question that uses Joomla coding standards which you should be using ;)

Comment: Ok, I guess it is impossible to do what I want here, thanks for your help anyway

Comment: I would start by updating the error function of the ajax call to the following. This will actually print the error response as an object that will give you what is returned (including any php errors) and such. With what you have, you will never see any error that is produced: `error: function (x, status, error) {
   console.log(status + '-' + error);
   console.log(x);
  }`

Comment: Hi, I did just that, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257799/get-joomla-user-id-using-a-jquery-ajax