# Get Joomla user_id using a Jquery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla

I have the following PHP script file.php in my Joomla site:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$usr_id = $user->get('id');
```

If I run it directly, using in HTML:

```
include_once "file.php";
```

It will get the user id, no problem.

However, if run it through an Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "other.php",
...
```

Where other.php is:

```
include_once "file.php";
```

I get the error:

```
Fatal error:  Class 'JFactory' not found in file.php on line 3
```

Why? Any help!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the Joomla library in order to use the `JFactory` class. To import the library, add the following to the top of your file:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) ).'/../..' );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/libraries/joomla/factory.php' );

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
```

Comment: I replaced JPATH_BASE by $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] since it was pointing to the wrong directories. Now, it is picking the right ones, but I get the error: No configuration file found and no installation code available. Exiting...

Comment: Do you have a *configuration.php* in the root of your Joomla folder? Cause this error usually means you don't and thus it thinks Joomla isn't installed. By the way, what version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: Yes, I have configuration.php at the root folder. I'm using J 2.5.14

Comment: and if you `var_dump(JPATH_BASE);` what do you get? You should get the path of the root of your Joomla directory

Comment: I get string(38) and the directory where the script is located: .../php/

Comment: Ok that's not right then. so where if your php file in respect to the root of your Joomla site? Can you please add your folder tree to your question as it's rather essential to be able to answer the question correctly

Comment: The structure is like this:
public_html/Apps
public_html/Apps/files
public_html/Apps/php

Inside the php folder, I have the php scripts and inside the files, I want to have folders with user ids that contain json files with their data

Comment: and is the Joomla site in `public_html/` ?

Comment: `define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__).'/../..' );` use this instead

Comment: Hi, I do get a warning, like: <b>Warning</b>:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent
But it is creating the directory and the file!!!